# MSSQL Server to PHP Array to JSON Encode to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, json, sql-server, highcharts

I have very simple data that has come from my MSSQL Server to a JSON_Encode.

Here is my PHP Code (located in myPHPFile.php):

```
<?php
$serverName = "MyServer";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"MyDatabase", "UID"=>"MyUID", "PWD"=>"MyPWD");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


$tsql = "SELECT * FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyView] ORDER BY Year";  

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql); 

$rows = array();
while($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $res[] = $r;
}

print json_encode($res, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);  
?>
```

That gives me the following print:

```
[{"Year":2016,"Number":41},{"Year":2017,"Number":512},{"Year":2018,"Number":1895},{"Year":2019,"Number":3132}]
```

Great. There's the data.

I've tried every tutorial, every highcharts forum post, and every stackoverflow question to get this simple data from my php file in JSON format, into a Highcharts Chart. Perhaps I am missing something obvious.

So let's look at my HTML file:

In the head:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("myPHPFile.php", function(json) {

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: { text: 'Year'}
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Number'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                series: json
            });
        });

    });

});
        </script>
```

And then obviously my div

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

What am I missing? The HTML window is just blank. No chart rendered.

Comment: Does the correct information get logged when you add `console.log` under `function(json)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Highchart examples](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels) show another example to setup the chart. The following format can be used:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("myPHPFile.php", function(json) {
    var series = json.map(function(record){
        return [record.Year, record.Number];
    })

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Year'
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Number'
        },
      },
      series: [{
        data: series
      }],
    });

  });
});
```

Checkout the live demo below:

```js
const data = [{
  "Year": 2016,
  "Number": 41
}, {
  "Year": 2017,
  "Number": 512
}, {
  "Year": 2018,
  "Number": 1895
}, {
  "Year": 2019,
  "Number": 3132
}];

const series = data.map(record => [record.Year, record.Number])

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'line',
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Year'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Number'
    },
  },
  series: [{
    data: series
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```